# Wordpress & PHP Looping within array of arrray that is not named?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

hoping this is a simple question. I can't find a answer as to how to target a array within a array when looping that isn't named. For example, I ultimately need to end up with a result like this:

```
      $args = array(
            'role' => 'artist',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    // $medium_array,
                    array(
                        'key' => 'artist_medium',
                        'value' => 'Wood',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'artist_medium',
                        'value' => 'Painting',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'studio_region_location',
                     'value' => 'London',
                     'compare' => 'LIKE',

)
            )
        );
```

What i've been doing is succesfully looping into $meta_query[], but what I can't figure out is how do I get into that second array within 'meta_query'. I tried the following but didn't have luck:

```
$_POST['mediumType'] = array('Wood', 'Painting');
$_POST['locationType'] = array('London');

 $meta_query = array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array('relation' => 'OR')
        );

        foreach ($_POST['mediumType'] as $val){
            $meta_query[][] = array(
                'key' => 'artist_medium',
                'value'=> $val,
                'compare' =>'LIKE'
            );
        }

        foreach ($_POST['locationType'] as $loc){
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => 'studio_region_location',
                'value'=> $loc,
                'compare' =>'LIKE'
            );
        }
```

So hoping someone can help. I know i'm missing something obvious here, but through Google searches all I could find was how to target that sub array if its named.  This is what a print_r reports that above code providing:

```
Array ( [role] => artist [orderby] => meta_value [order] => ASC [meta_query] => Array ( [relation] => AND [0] => Array ( [relation] => OR ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => artist_medium [value] => Fabric - decorative [compare] => LIKE ) ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => artist_medium [value] => Metal [compare] => LIKE ) ) [3] => Array ( [key] => studio_region_location [value] => Dublin / Marlborough / Jaffrey [compare] => LIKE ) ) )
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty certain that once inside the nested array, as long as you don't call your array key `relation`, `key` or `value`, you can name it anything which means you can target it later. Try using `$meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND', 'FAKE_KEY' => array('relation' => 'OR'));`

Comment: Well, the `print_r` has shown you exactly what the keys are - they are numeric. So have you tried using them?

Comment: I tried the numeric one and the fake key one which does target, but it seems to not add any additional arrays onto the uh array except for one; which i'm sure is due to me missing something. This is what I used:

ach ($_POST['mediumType'] as $val){
            $meta_query[1] = array(
                'key' => 'artist_medium',
                'value'=> $val,
                'compare' =>'LIKE'
            );

Comment: I find this question to be Unclear.  Why can't we have a [mcve]?  What is in `$_POST`? What is the exact desired result based on your sample `$_POST` data?

Comment: Sorry, just updated with some test data. and a exact desired result up top.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, thanks to the help of everyone. :) Numeric *or* the fake key name works!

```
 foreach ($_POST['mediumType'] as $val){
            $meta_query[0][] = array(
                'key' => 'artist_medium',
                'value'=> $val,
                'compare' =>'LIKE'
            );
        }
```